# Navigation left/right buttons disappeared after upgrading to latest Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

After upgrading my Xcode to the latest 6.3 I'm noticing that when I try to programmatically add left and right bar button items, the button/text does not appear. I tried using .plain, .done, and .bordered button styles but no matter what they don't show up now and the user can't navigate anymore. This is a non-traditional navigation setup (it's a little hack - I do a present view controller to take you to a completely isolated/disconnected navigation view controller that has one item on it, so nothing is actually pushed on the stack)

the code that used to work in the previous version was:

```
 self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(title: LocalizedString("Add"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "btnAdd:"), animated: true)
```

What do you think happened now? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the size, click at bottom of the Main.storyboard 'wCompact hAny' and reselect the size to show, such as one square width and 3 squares height.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in the page load:

```
    var navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: LocalizedString("Edit")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: LocalizedString("Back"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "btnBack:");
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.pushNavigationItem(navigationItem, animated: false)
```

Not completely sure why the previous method stopped working, but this is now working for me so wanted to share. Hope it helps someone.